# How to identify which 3rd party flash object called a Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, flash

I have a page with multiple flash objects which are written by a third party and thus can't be changed. They call a JS function but don't seem to pass any identifying parameters. Is there any way to determine inside the function which flash object called it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be cross-browser compatible, and in the end you may find only that "Flash" is calling the function, rather than a specific movie, but this is the only way I can think of:

```
function myFunction() {
   if (myFunction.caller) {
      console.log("This function's caller is " + myFunction.caller);
    } 
    else {
      console.log("This function was called directly");
    }
    /* rest of function */
}
```

This should run in Firefox and will log to the console.

Comment: Sadly it only gives me "This function was called directly". Thanks though. :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the only information a function gets from the place that called it is whatever parameters are passed in with the call.